# Suggestions For .io Client Rendering

Tags: javascript, socket.io, html5-canvas

I am currently working on an .io game, using socket.io for communication. All of the game logic is OOP and is all contained in a instance of the GameLogic class. I am trying to decide the best way to send out the graphic information and to have it displayed. I am looking for **minimal code** on the client’s  end,  so something like

```
const canvas = document.getElementById(‘canvass’)
const ctx = canvas.getContext(‘2d’)


const socket = io();
socket.on(‘Graphics Package’, (data) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0,        innerWidth, innerHeight)
    for(let i in data){
        data[i].display(ctx);
    }

});
```

Would be optimal

Is this possible, or is there a better way to do this? If so, what is it?

Comment: A tutorial I found really useful and progressive is Raining Chain's multiplayer JS tutorial it teaches you the basics of multiplayer game development which I think is where you should start in this case, because rendering directly from a package will prove very tedious in the long run, believe me :). Heres the link to the tutorial https://scripterswar.com/tutorial/nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this qusetion, I have settled on a relatively simple OOP appoach to this problem. I have a large Sceen object, which holds all the information about each object that is going to be displayed. It is sent out to the clients, how each have their own 'interpter' if you will. This is the server code:

```
class Scene{
   constructor(){
       this.objs = new Object();
   }
   addCircle(id,x,y,r,col){
       this.objs[id]={
           type: 'circle',
           x: x,
           y: y,
           r: r,
           col: col
       };
   }
   addRect(id, x,y,w,h,col){
       this.objs[id] = {
           type: 'rect',
           x: x,
           y: y,
           w: w,
           h: h,
           col: col
       };
   }
   addPath(id, col, ...verts){
       this.objs[id] = {
           type: 'path',
           col: col,
           verts: verts
       };
   }
   render(socket){
       socket.emit('Scene Package',this.objs);
   }
}

scene = new Scene();
// Add a rectange
scene.addRect(socket.id, 50,50,50,50,"blue");
scene.render(socket);
```

And the (unfinished) client code looks like this:

```
socket.on('Scene Package',(data) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, innerWidth,innerHeight)
    for(let i in data){
        shape = data[i]
        if(shape){
            switch(shape.type){
                case 'circle':
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = shape.col;
                    ctx.arc(shape.x, shape.y, shape.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
                    ctx.fill();
                break;
                case 'rect':
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = shape.col;
                    ctx.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.w, shape.h);
                break;
                case 'path':
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = shape.col;
                    ctx.arc(shape.x, shape.y, shape.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This way I can draw on a universal canvas and have control over the syntax. This has given me very few (if at all any) bugs, and should allow easy expandability in terms of shapes and features.